# How to remove bookmarks from sidebar in Nautilus on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, gtk

How do I remove the bookmarks for Pictures, Music, Videos, etc. from the Nautilus sidebar?

This is not a duplicate, as all the other variations of this question DO NOT work for version Ubuntu 18.04 (having tried them all) which is why I am asking this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the file:

```
$HOME/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks
```

and remove all the lines that correspond to the folders you want to remove from the sidebar. My end product looked like this:

```
file:///home/username/Downloads
```

replace 'username' with your username.

Comment: Tried this, isn't working for me.

Comment: Doesn't work. Not sure its' actually doable looking at the GUI of Nautilus these bookmarks look heavily integrated...