# Remove all Nautilus bookmarks, or set sane defaults

Tags: nautilus, gtk3

Nautilus has a Bookmarks section below the Places and Devices in the sidebar.

I can add and remove bookmarks from this section using the Nautilus GUI

I can also add and remove bookmarks by editing the file `~/.config/gtk3.0/bookmarks`

However if I remove *all* the bookmarks, then *close* and *re-open* Nautilus, five "default" bookmarks are added

```
file:///home/zeimusu/Documents
file:///home/zeimusu/Music
file:///home/zeimusu/Pictures
file:///home/zeimusu/Videos
file:///home/zeimusu/Downloads
```

This is somewhat surprising, as there is no user "zeimusu" on the system  (I created a user with this name years ago to practise adding and removing users)  There is no folder /home/zeimusu. My username isn't "zeimusu"

I want to remove these bookmarks and prevent them from being recreated.

I'd also like to know why it re-creates exactly those bookmarks by default and not a more useful set.

Prior research:

[How to remove items from Places sidebar in Nautilus 3.6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264280/how-to-remove-items-from-places-sidebar-in-nautilus-3-6)

This is about the Places links, not the bookmarks.  Other questions I've seen are about the XDG links, and not the custom bookmarks. eg [Nautilus doesn't allow adding/removing bookmarks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363302/nautilus-doesnt-allow-adding-removing-bookmarks)

[How to remove bookmarks from sidebar in Nautilus on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079400/how-to-remove-bookmarks-from-sidebar-in-nautilus-on-ubuntu-18-04)

This is related but seems to be about removing bookmarks, not about preventing their return. It also isn't clear if the user is actually talking about custom bookmarks or XDG links in Places.